# Отображение меню на телефоне

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Как правильно отобразить меню на телефоне с помощью jquery. Чтобы было вот так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас меню выглядит [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылку на код прилагаю: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GQodzQ

```
введите сюда код
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у `.cd-main-nav` измените `right: 0px` на `right: -260px`

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @ПавелГуров, не за что:)